# Where can I find ibus "Keyboard Input Methods"?

Tags: keyboard-layout, language-support, ibus

Earlier I used to activate Bangla (Unijoy) layout from ibus preference. Accessed ibus Keyboard Input Methods, ibus preference would only show up a handful of chinese scripts. I had to install "ibus-m17n" to get the whole package which included the unijoy layout.

[image]

However, starting 13.10, I can't find the ibus preference/Keyboard Input Method screen at all. It's been replaced by text entry field, where there are Bengali layouts but not Unijoy. Terminal shows that ibus is installed but I can't bring up the front-end. I even installed ibus-m17n but still the unijoy layout doesn't show up.

[image]

I know it wouldn't matter for a lot of people here since it's just a local language, but I need it. I'm a journalist and run a few bilingual websites where I need to write a lot -- that includes Bangla and English. I must write Bangla using the layout that I -- and a lot of people over here -- am familiar with most.

Answer (score 3):

Okay guys I found the solution:

Running `ibus-setup` from the terminal brings up the preferences window that I have been missing. :)

Comment: Please mark this question as solved and this answer as the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps this guy laid out here... Hope this helps. :)

http://ottopor.com/ottopor/en/it/unijoy-layout-in-ubuntu-13-10-gnome-remix/

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did everything this guy said, but still Unijoy isn't showing up. I left a comment on this post. Hope he finds out fast.

Thanks for the link.